# Spark Streaming first job requires more time than following jobs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I noticed that when I start the Spark Streaming application the first job takes more time than the following ones even when there are no input data. I also noticed that the first job when input data arrives requires a processing time greater than the following. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Thank You

Comment: might have something to do with ```spark.sql.shuffle.partitions``` value set if you are running any ```wide transformations```

Comment: I have the same question as you